# Possible to compress an image and possibly change to different type?

Tags: java, image-processing

I'm having a problem finding an answer for this...

What I want is a method that takes in a byte array for a given image and compresses it. If I've understood things correctly, png is a good way to compress an image if it has a lot of the same colors, so it would be nice to be able to convert the mime-type to png as well during the process. That is, if the image is not allready png format.

This is what I have in mind:

```
public static byte[] compressImage(byte[] imagebytes) {

    //do the compression here

    return imagebytes;
}
```

Comment: you do not know the image format beforehand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it through Java Image API but I discourage this because it's not so powerful neither so cool to use.

A better solution would be to interface to [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) through [JMagick](http://www.jmagick.org/). It will be somewhat more complex to get into but you will have a fully fledged flexible engine to work with images (under many formats)..

If you want to keep it the old way then start from the Oracle tutorial [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/index.html)

Comment: thanks for your quick response :) Do you have any good reasons for not using the Java Image API other than that it is not so cool? If it is sufficient for this small problem I mean...

Comment: the fact is that it is quite limited, unable to support many formats (yes for PNG and JPEG but I'm not sure about all kinds of PNGs or JPEGs). However it's more a matter of personal taste I think, for your problem __ImageMagick__ can be overkill, you are right.. just try with Java Image API and hope it's enough :)